# D-Link DFL-800 настройка VPN сервера

Tags: сеть, firewall, vpn, маршрутизация, маршрутизатор

Необходимо на "DFL-800" (192.168.1.1/24) настроить VPN сервер для подсоединения удалённого офиса. Там на входе тоже стоит "DFL-800 (2)" который будет VPN клиентом. "DES-3526" и имеет ip 223.0.0.1/24 он вроде как эмулирует WAN (с внешкой проблематично). Соответственно "DES-3526" подключается к обоим "DFL-800" через "WAN1". По хорошему мне нужно при этом ещё использовать и SSL, но хотя бы без него реализовать.Естественно, что я не сидел на месте и пытался его настроить используя следующий мануал:[Настройка PPTP сервера на DFL-210/800/1600/2500 для доступа удаленных пользователей.][1]Но пока безрезультатно. VPN на XP и Ubuntu 13.10 не поднимается. Ошибка 800:" VPN-сервер недоступен, или параметры безопасности для данного подключения настроены не верно"![alt text][2]  [1]: http://dlink.ru/ru/faq/85/479.html  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug3Sd.jpg

Comment: А зачем вы пытаетесь сделать тоннель через PPTP? Там же через IPSec есть! Вот тут описано, правда на примере DFL-700, но надеюсь, что поможет: http://dlink.ru/ru/faq/92/518.html

Comment: Сегодня сам наткнулся на этот ман, но применить его не смог.

Comment: А почему? Поподробнее, пожалуйста! В 800-х IPSec тоже ведь есть!

Comment: там интерфейс настройки совершенно отличается. понимаю что звучит глупо, но на dfl-800 всё по другому.

Comment: Вот тут вроде есть: http://www.dlink.ru/ru/faq/92/927.html Проверить не могу, нету у меня такого девайса!ЗЫ: Там динамический описан. Если статический - то вообще всё намного проще, при наличии некоторых знаний.

Comment: благодарю. в понедельник проверю

Comment: DFL-800 (lan - 192.168.1.1); DFL-800(2)(lan - 192.168.2.1) к обоим подключено по ПК. И оба DFL соединены через WAN1 друг с другом (можно и по другому). Как с одного ПК на другой попасть?Собрал всё как в последнем мане, но не понятно как оно должно работать. WAN1 to WAN1 ни как не отображаются вообще

Comment: Хм. В моем случае впн по IPSec поднялся только после того, как я на ПК за длинком настроил route до удаленной сети через локальный длинк, и запустил пинг. VPN сразу снюхался (достаточно настроить PSK и удаленные сети правильно). На обеих сторонах стоит add route for destination network.

Comment: То есть так: на каждом длинке точка IPsec VPN, local network==lannet, remote network=(локальная сеть с той стороны, создать объект), remote endpoint=(wan ip второго длинка), авторизация=PSK (задать одинаковые), остальные настройки должны в точности совпадать. И правила на обеих сторонах настроить хотя бы тупо permit all_services в обе стороны. После чего проверить, куда ходят пакеты, направленные в сторону удаленной сети, и должно взлететь. Дальше только логи длинков копать.